# Getting this error when deploying a model using FLASK: TypeError: Input data can not be a list

Tags: python-3.x, flask, deployment, model, web-deployment

This is the error I am getting:

It's happening at "prediction = model.predict(final_features)"

```
TypeError: Input data can not be a list.

Traceback (most recent call last)
Open an interactive python shell in this frameprediction = model.predict(final_features)
[console ready]
```

Here is my app.py code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
import numpy as np
import pickle


# initialize the flask app
app = Flask(__name__)

# open the pickle file in the read mode
model = pickle.load(open('model.pkl', 'rb'))

# root node for API URL
@app.route('/')
def home():
   return render_template('index.html') # rewrite to the index.html file

# create another API
@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def predict():
   '''
   For rendering results on HTML GUI
   '''
# int value of dependent variables
int_features = [int(x) for x in request.form.values()]

# convert the above to the array
final_features = [np.array(int_features)]

# perform prediction
prediction = model.predict(final_features)
print(prediction)

# get the prediction
output = round(prediction[0], 2)

return render_template('index.html', prediction_text='The predicted number of hours you listen to K-Pop is {} hours'.format(output))

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run(debug=True)
```

Not sure why I am getting an error that input data can not be a list.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to modify

```
# convert the above to the array
final_features = [np.array(int_features)]
```

to

```
# convert the above to the array
final_features = np.array(int_features)
```

also, `print(final_features)`

It is always tricky to convert web input to the right format. I feel it is a tiny bug somewhere.

Comment: Now I'm getting this error: ValueError: ('Expecting 2 dimensional numpy.ndarray, got: ', (5,))

Comment: print(final_features)

Comment: Not sure how to check that.. it won't print it on the web version

Comment: I looked up how to make the print statement appear on the console, but everything I tried didn't work.

Comment: You already did all the hard part! Form data gets transferred in the model eventually. There is a error in data shape/type/format though.

Comment: Yeah.. not quite sure what the shape or type it should be. I was following the example here. 

https://www.kdnuggets.com/2019/10/easily-deploy-machine-learning-models-using-flask.html

Comment: Try to debug with adding `print()` statements. Without any debug information you are solving without the lights on.